# MongoDB Add/Replace Element from Separate Collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have two mongodb collections, **processes** and **users** and below I have example docs from within them. I am trying to query a process document but replace the userID's that are nested in the event objects with the names of the users instead of their ID's. What is the best way to do that given I may have several nested objects within the 'history' object? (Running on node and using the native driver, not using mongoose).

**Process Document**

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId('63d96b68e7b92dceb334f4cb'),
    status: 'active',
    history: {
        {
            type: 'created',
            userID: '61e77cdedde2dbe1cbf8a250',
            date: 'Tue Jan 31 2023 17:31:32 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
        },
        {
            type: 'updated',
            userID: 'd6xMtHTIX3QO0FifUPgoJLOLz872',
            date: 'Tue Jan 31 2023 18:31:32 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
        },
        {
            type: 'updated',
            userID: '61e77cdedde2dbe1cbf8a250',
            date: 'Tue Jan 31 2023 19:31:32 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
        },

    }
}
```

**User 1 Document**

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId('d6xMtHTIX3QO0FifUPgoJLOLz872'),
    email: 'something@something.com',
    firstname: 'Bobby',
    lastname: 'Tables',
}
```

**User 2 Document**

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId('61e77cdedde2dbe1cbf8a250'),
    email: 'something2@something.com',
    firstname: 'Jenny',
    lastname: 'Tables',
}
```

**Actual outpt I'm looking for**

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId('63d96b68e7b92dceb334f4cb'),
    status: 'active',
    history: {
        {
            type: 'created',
            userName: 'Jenny Tables',
            date: 'Tue Jan 31 2023 17:31:32 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
        },
        {
            type: 'updated',
            userName: 'Bobby Tables',
            date: 'Tue Jan 31 2023 18:31:32 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
        },
        {
            type: 'updated',
            userName: 'Jenny Tables',
            date: 'Tue Jan 31 2023 19:31:32 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
        },

    }
}
```

**Here is what I have tried**, which I can get to yield existing data and update one record's name, but not all of them:

```js
try {
    const db = mongo.getDB();
    const data = db.collection("processes");
    data.aggregate([
        {$sort: {_id: -1}}, 
        {$lookup: {from: 'users', localField: 'history.userID', foreignField: '_id', as: 'User'}},
        {$unwind: '$User'},
        {$addFields: {"history.userName": { '$concat': ['$User.firstname', ' ', '$User.lastname']}}},
        {$project:{_id: 1, status: 1, history: 1}}
    ]).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send('Database array error.');
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).send(result);
    });

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send('Database error.');
}
```

**EDIT:**

The former answer is likely correct, the error I'm getting is due to using a uid instead of _id on the user collection (I believe):

Here is my attempt:

```js
data.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$history"},
    {"$lookup": {from: "users", localField: "history.userID", foreignField: "uid", as: "userLookup"}},
    {$unwind: "$userLookup"},
    {$project: {status: 1, history: {type: "$history.type", userName: {"$concat": ["$userLookup.firstname"," ","$userLookup.lastname"]}, date: "$history.date"}}},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id",status: {$first: "$status"}, history: {push: "$history"}}},
    {"$merge": {into: "process", on: "_id",whenMatched: "merge"}}
]).toArray(function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (err)
    {
        res.status(500).send('Database array error.');
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
        res.status(200).send(result);
});
```

User Document (now):

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId('d6xMtHTIX3QO0FifUPgoJLOLz872'),
    uid: 'werwevmA5gZ2Ky2MUuSAj6TJiZz1',
    email: 'something@something.com',
    firstname: 'Bobby',
    lastname: 'Tables',
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first `$unwind` the history array. Perform `$lookup` to the `user` collection. Build the new history object. Finally `$group` back into original form and `$merge` to update to the collection.

```js
db.processes.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$history"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "users",
      localField: "history.userID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$userLookup"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      status: 1,
      history: {
        type: "$history.type",
        userName: {
          "$concat": [
            "$userLookup.firstname",
            " ",
            "$userLookup.lastname"
          ]
        },
        date: "$history.date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      status: {
        $first: "$status"
      },
      history: {
        $push: "$history"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      into: "process",
      on: "_id",
      whenMatched: "merge"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ijkR-8m73xx)

Comment: This appears to work but how would it change if history was no longer an object, and instead was an array?

Comment: @supremesector Isn't history an array? I thought it was a typo so I make it an array in my playground. If it is an object, your sample json documents will not be a valid one.

Comment: nevermind I see you gave your answer based on history being an array. I'm getting a MongoServerError: The field 'history' must be an accumulator object error.

Comment: @supremesector Updated my answer based on your latest updates. You are actually very close. I just fixed 2 things: 1. in `$lookup` use `_id` instead of `uid` 2. fixed a typo in `$group`. Note the dollar sign before push

Comment: the error is gone but I want to use uid as the foreign field instead of _id. If I change the foreign field to uid, this yields an empty array

Comment: @supremesector you can always change the `$lookup` according to your needs. Just make sure the linkage is correct so you can look up some records as expected.

Comment: I got it, I removed your merge line (as it was pushing this into a separate collection "process", I just changed the foreign field and it works now. Thank you!